# MVC ModelBinding from android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have an issue trying to bind some values in my controller. I am POSTING a JSONObject from Android, containing two simple values, firstname and surname.

The file is being created on my machine (file.txt) but the result is blank. It doesn't seem to be binding my values from my Android request.

I.E, the output in the file is:   Hi, :

Could anyone cast their eye on this and see what is wrong?

Many Thanks.

Android Code:

```
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/");

                JSONObject person = new JSONObject();
                person.put("firstname","Bob");
                person.put("surname","Builder");
                StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(person.toString());
                stringEntity.setContentType("application/json");
                post.setEntity(stringEntity);

                client.execute(post);
```

MVC:

```
public class Person
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public void create(string result)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\AndroidAPI\file.txt", "Hi, "+result);
    }
}
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(Person person)
    {
        Person pp = new Person();
        pp.create(pp.firstname + " : " + pp.surname);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: try with [HttpPost] attribute on your Index(Person person) Method:

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person person)
    {

Answer (score 0):

I tried writing this in the comment but Format was not clear:

As your request is POST from android I think you should add `[HttpPost]` attribute to your method in Controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Person person)
    {
        Person pp = new Person();
        pp.create(pp.firstname + " : " + pp.surname);
        return View();
    }
}
```